# Twilio: Integrate existing number?

Tags: twilio

Twilio newbie here.  Is it possible to integrate with a customer's existing VoIP (or even landline) number?  I've searched, but haven't been able to find substantial information on the topic.  I'm interest in grabbing call data from the API for use with an existing SaaS application I've built, but my customer base cannot change their phone number. Thanks for your time.

Comment: can you add sms service to an existing land line with twilio but keep the voice with your existing carrier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have the option of transferiing your phone number to Twilio if you client is open to that idea:

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/phone-numbers/i-already-have-a-phone-number-i-love-can-i-port-it-to-twilio

Painless and free process.

and, almost as important, if you need to, you can take the number back with you to another carrier:

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/porting/how-do-i-port-my-numbers-away-from-twilio

Comment: I note the FAQ states: _At this time we are not able to port numbers into Twilio from any country other than the US._